# Cannot Install This Hardware - Android Hardware Device Setup

Tags: android, eclipse, android-hardware, usb-debugging

I ran into a problem trying to set up a hardware device for testing Android applications using Eclipse.

After following the ["Using Hardware Devices"](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) guide from Android and going to their link in step 3 I attempted to follow the steps there. I went to their OEM drivers table and clicked on Samsung and found my product had no available downloads. However, as I continued I discovered that the driver for my Samsung Galaxy Tab III was already on my computer. This happened when I followed the steps listed under "Windows" and "Or, upgrade and existing Android USB driver . . . " and I get to the last few steps and input the file location . . .

```
C:\Software\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\
```

I get the following error from the update wizard:

```
"The hardware was not installed because the wizard cannot find the necessary software".
```

So what should I do now? Are the files I have downloaded from Android out-of-date? Any help would be greatly appreciated guys!

Thanks,
Mikayla

Comment: One thing you can try is to check %systemroot%\setupapi.log and see what type of PNPID it found for your device.  You can then add that to the driver .inf and try to re-install.  This has worked for me before.

Comment: You can download driver from Samsung's website and re-install again. The usb driver installed from Android SDK manager is not compatible with Samsung's device.

Comment: Peter, where can I find the PNPID? I opened the file but I do not know where that is located.

Comment: @user2502516 You can delete or rename that setupapi.log and plug in your device again.  Windows will print the PNPID that it finds and print whether it can find a driver or not.  You can trick it into using your driver by modifying the .inf.  BTW, when you reply to someone on StackOverflow pls use the '@' followed by their name.  That way your reply will appear in their notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is a great software that Samsung provides that includes the capability to backup the device, after [downloading it](http://content.samsung.com/us/contents/aboutn/kiesIntro.do) the device showed up in Eclipse.